# Is there a function how can i close my datePicker of PrimeNG?

Tags: angular, primeng, primeng-calendar

i use the component Calender of PrimeNG version 6. Angular Version 9. Is there a function if, for example, I click on the datepicker from the name-input-field from there and the date field opens and I click the focus on Name again, the datepicker closes? Focusout only works when I'm in the date input field. I would like to close the datepicker when another field has focus. I already use the focusout.

```
(focusout)="close()"
```

Answer (score 0):

see the [methods of Calendar](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/showcase/#/calendar)

You find `toggle` method, so the only is call this method. For this, from the .html you can use a template reference variable and use,e.g.

```
<p-calendar #myvariable inputId="basic" [(ngModel)]="date1"></p-calendar>

<button (click)="myvariable.toggle()">click</button>
```

Is you want to do from code, you use `ViewChild` to "get" the p-calendar

```
@ViewChild('myvariable') calendar:any;
//and in any place
this.calendar.toggle()
```

**Update** we can check if is open using some like

```
<input (focus)="myvariable.overlayVisible && myvariable.toggle()">
```

See the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-calendar-demo-9xbkcv?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: click Event only works if data-input was clicked.  I would like to close the datepicker when another field has focus. If i click another inputfield,

Comment: @chandee,  don't work some like `<input (focus)="calendar.overlayVisible && calendar.toggle()">`? see a [simple stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-calendar-demo-9xbkcv?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: toggle is not supported for primeNG version 6.

Comment: try `hideOverlay()` to hide and `showOverLay()` to show it